# There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am getting this error. It was working fine from six months. I haven't changed anything.

Troubleshoot:

1. I have changed to Magento default theme.
2. Updated all core files and extensions.
3. Changed payment gateway
4. Change checkout method

Still nott working.

Please check system log and exception.log

Can anybody help me? I tried everything but stuck here 10 hours of troubleshooting.

exception.log
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwweON8IpmfWaHdqbEJIUUdnRTQ/view?usp=sharing

system.log
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwweON8IpmfWUW03ZWhkYUVkUTQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that might be going on:

#### First Issue:

```
2015-09-28T17:11:33+00:00 ERR (3):
```

exception 'Zend_Mail_Exception' with message 'Subject set twice' in /var/www/vhosts/theshowerdoctors.ie/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Mail.php:933

The last line in exception.log is this. Seeing the stack trace, I would disable the extension `Mage_Advancedsmtp`. To do this, open `app/etc/modules/Mage_Advancedsmtp.xml`, and change the value of the `<active>` node to be `false`.

#### Second Issue:

I don't think this is causing a problem, but it looks to be there is a problem with permissions for your LESS files. Your LESS compiler is triggering an exception, as it can't find the files to compile. Since there is no URLs logged with the stack trace, I can't tell whether this is also causing the problem.

```
Exception.log: exception 'Exception' with message 'load error: failed to find ...'

System.log:Warning: is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(.../skin/frontend/mtbelano/default/css/_config/design_default.less) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/theshowerdoctors.ie/:/tmp/)  in /var/www/vhosts/theshowerdoctors.ie/httpdocs/lib/Soczed/less/lessc.inc.php on line 2378
```

This is a PHP `open_basedir()` issue. The php script cannot access the LESS file. If this is what is causing the problem, then your web host probably changed permissions on your server, which would cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all orders and its working. Some order was clashing and I don't know why. really strange